# For what value of $x\in\Bbb R$ does the integral converge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

improper integral:
$$f(x)=\int_2^{\infty}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{y\ln (y+x)$$

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried?

Comment: I used comparison test but don't know how to find a lower bound function.

Comment: $\forall x\in\Bbb R\quad\dfrac1{y\sqrt{\ln (y+x^2)}}\sim_{y\to+\infty}\dfrac1{y\sqrt{\ln y}}.$

Comment: It's an upper bound. I want the lower bound function.

Comment: It is more than an upper bound. It is an asymptotic equivalent (i.e. the quotient tends to $1$) hence the two integrals behave the same. You will easily find that the second one diverges.

Comment: Can you please post an explanation. I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_x(y):=\dfrac1{y\sqrt{\ln (y+x^2)}}(>0).$

$\forall x\in\Bbb R\quad f_x(y)\sim_{y\to+\infty}f_0(y),$ i.e.
$\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{f_x(y)}{f_0(y)}=1.$

Therefore, $f_x(y)\ge\frac12f_0(y)$ for $y$ big enough.

But $\int_2^\infty f_0(y)\,\mathrm dy=\int_{\ln 2}^\infty\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt t}=+\infty,$ so $\int_2^\infty f_x(y)\,\mathrm dy$ is divergent for every $x\in\Bbb R.$